# Error in Angular2 component when using Youtube Typescript from DefinitelyTyped

Tags: angular, typescript

I have installed the youtube typescript types from DefinitelyTyped 
`npm install @types/youtube --save`

I have to embed the youtube player in my Angular 2 project, in a component. 
Why do I get error in calling the constructor?

--Edits-- 
Here is the code for the component:

```
/// <reference path="../../../../node_modules/@types/youtube/index.d.ts" />

import {
  Component,
  OnInit
} from '@angular/core';



@Component({
  selector: 'app-video',
  templateUrl: './video.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./video.component.css']

})

export class VideoComponent implements OnInit {

  private id: string = 'qDuKsiwS5xw';
  player: YT.Player;
  done = false;

  youtubelink: string = 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/videoseries?list=PLbTNZNtSmrpoUVan0LVqTP3qu_9_aMr6P';

  constructor() {

    this.player = new YT.Player('player', {
        height: 390,
        width: 640,
        videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE',
        events: {
            'onReady': this.onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': this.onStateChange
        }
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

  onStateChange(event) {
    console.log('player state', event.data);
  }
  // 4. The API will call this function when the video player is ready.
  onPlayerReady(event) {
    event.target.playVideo();
  }
  // 5. The API calls this function when the player's state changes.
  //    The function indicates that when playing a video (state=1),
  //    the player should play for six seconds and then stop.
  onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && !this.done) {
      setTimeout(this.stopVideo, 6000);
      this.done = true;
    }
  }

  stopVideo() {
    this.player.stopVideo();
  }

}
```

And I have tsconfig.json file

```
"files": [ "node_modules/@types/youtube/index.d.ts" ]
```

And when I run this in the Chrome Developer Console, here is the error message I am getting:

```
core.es5.js:1020 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: YT.Player is not a constructor
TypeError: YT.Player is not a constructor
    at new VideoComponent (video.component.ts:27)
    at createClass (core.es5.js:10910)
    at createDirectiveInstance (core.es5.js:10744)
    at createViewNodes (core.es5.js:12180)
    at callViewAction (core.es5.js:12626)
    at execComponentViewsAction (core.es5.js:12535)
    at createViewNodes (core.es5.js:12207)
    at createRootView (core.es5.js:12075)
    at callWithDebugContext (core.es5.js:13458)
    at Object.debugCreateRootView [as createRootView] (core.es5.js:12775)
    at new VideoComponent (video.component.ts:27)
    at createClass (core.es5.js:10910)
    at createDirectiveInstance (core.es5.js:10744)
    at createViewNodes (core.es5.js:12180)
    at callViewAction (core.es5.js:12626)
    at execComponentViewsAction (core.es5.js:12535)
    at createViewNodes (core.es5.js:12207)
    at createRootView (core.es5.js:12075)
    at callWithDebugContext (core.es5.js:13458)
    at Object.debugCreateRootView [as createRootView] (core.es5.js:12775)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:783)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:754)
    at zone.js:831
    at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:424)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.es5.js:3881)
    at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:423)
    at Zone.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (zone.js:191)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:595)
    at <anonymous>
```

Thanks, Rajesh

Comment: Its a global variable named `YT`.

Comment: First of all, `@types/youtube` does not provide any "component" that you can use in your Angular app. Looks like your understanding of "Typescript" and "Component" is wrong. Those are two different things entirely. All `@types/youtube` is providing is, typescript definitions for Youtube developer API.

Comment: why do I get error in calling the constructor of YT?

Answer (score 0):

I had to use the `ng2 youtube player` : https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-youtube-player

Answer (score 0):

Most like you're not waiting for the `onYouTubeIframeAPIReady` to have been called. The `YT.Player` exists (which is why you get an error as opposed to a null exception), but it isn't initialized yet.

Super quick test is to put a `setTimeout` for 1000ms on your player initialization, and then if that works create a promise that is resolved when the callback is called (by Youtube's JS). I put the following in a ScriptService that is injected into my YouTube component.

```
private globalCallbacks: any = {};

this.globalCallbacks[name] = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                    window[name] = () => {
                        resolve(true);
                    };
                });
```

Run this code with `name = 'onYouTubeIframeAPIReady'` and then you can

```
await globalCallbacks['onYouTubeIframeAPIReady']
```

whenever you need to create a player. Once it is called once then the promise will return immediately.